# React passing data or adding to state wrong

Tags: reactjs

When I leave this code as is, I will get the correct console.log (commented with "these appear correct") that I'm looking for. However when I replace the api_url with `http://localhost:9000/ipdata/${this.state.inputValue}` the console.log is blank. This is why I think I'm either passing the input value wrong or I'm adding it to the state wrong.

I would assume I'm adding it to the state wrong as the spans that I'm trying to render in order to output the data on the client aren't displaying anything either.

Heres my code ...

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: '', inputValue: '', result: {} };
  }

  async callAPI() {
    try {
      console.log('called API...');
      const api_url = `http://localhost:9000/ipdata/8.8.8.8`;
      const res = await fetch(api_url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const result = await res.json();
      // these appear correct
      console.log(result.city);
      console.log(result.region_code);
      console.log(result.zip);
      this.setState({ result });
    } catch (error) {
      // handle errors
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>IP Search</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })}
        />
        <button onClick={this.callAPI}>Search IP</button>
        <p>
          <span>{this.state.result.city}</span>
          <span>{this.state.result.region_code}</span>
          <span>{this.state.result.zip}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

API call on the Node server...

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
app.get('/ipdata/:ipaddress', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  const ipaddress = req.params.ipaddress;
  console.log(ipaddress);
  const api_url = `http://api.ipstack.com/${ipaddress}?access_key=API_KEY`;
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const json = await response.json();
  res.json(json);
});
```

Comment: Well, the default `this.state.inputValue` is `''` (an empty string). If you never edit your input field, the API request will fail.

Comment: are you using the same value in input ie. 8.8.8.8 before calling the ```callAPI``` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the way you set state, but the way you access it, because `callAPI` doesn't have access to `this`, so you get an error thrown inside the function and as you don't handle errors, it gets swollen. To make it work you either bind the function

```
onClick={this.callAPI.bind(this)}
```

or use arrow function instead

```
callAPI = async ()=> {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so caught up on this little bug. It works now!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted